# How to use a filter in a Struts1 application?

Tags: servlet-filters, struts-1

I have a Struts1 application and am unsuccessfully trying to get a filter to work in order to add headers/etc to the response after the action has completed, but am not able to get it to work.

By the time the struts action is completed and control is returned to my filter, the response is already committed.

web.xml:

```
   <filter>
      <filter-name>workflow</filter-name>
      <filter-class>webapp.session.WorkflowModifierFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>workflow</filter-name>
      <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
   </filter-mapping>


   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>config</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>debug</param-name>
         <param-value>0</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>detail</param-name>
         <param-value>2</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
```

My filter is the following:

```
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

      if( !servletResponse.isCommitted() )
          log.debug("Not Committed!  Can modify it!");

      filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);

      // depending on the response, I'd like to add headers here
      if( servletResponse.getStatus() == 200 )
          servletResponse.addIntHeader( "x-success", 1 );

      if( servletResponse.isCommitted() )
          log.debug("ACCCK!  Response Already Committed");
   }
```

However, I noticed that my `x-success` header was never added.  A little digging, and I noticed that my response was already returned/committed by the time the control returned to my filter chain.

What is the proper way to do this in `Struts1`?  Does the filter execution not supposed to wrap the entire servlet?  Why is my response being committed prior to my filter finishing?  Where else can I add headers based on the response (post action processing) in Struts1?

Comment: Use tiles or SiteMesh. That's what they're for. But why are you still using Struts 1? It's  been abandoned for years.

Comment: @jbnizet unfortunately the legacy app I'm working on is still using struts1 so I'm trying to work with it.  I'm actually trying to use aspectj to modify response headers before they are returned to the client and was augmenting an existing filter when I ran into this issue.  Sitemesh is more for the decoration and I wanted to keep the code centralized so I didn't want to start advising tiles classes.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `filterChain.doFilter` you pass control from your filter to requested page (ie Struts), which is then free to commit the response if it chooses.  Since you want to examine the result of the Struts servlet, you should create a response wrapper class (`extends HttpServletRequestWrapper`) and pass that to `filterChain.doFilter` rather than the response parameter that your filter is passed.

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
ServletResponse wrapper = new MyHttpServletRequestWrapper(httpResponse);
filter.doChain(servletRequest, wrapper);
```

The `HttpServletRequestWrapper` constructor accepts a `HttpServletResponse` as input and delegates all methods to the wrapped response, but you can override them in your class as necessary.  If you want to prevent the response from being committed you'll want to override methods such as `flushBuffer`, `getOutputSteam` (the returned output stream can be flushed, committing the response), and `getWriter`.

But you may not need to do that - try overriding the `setStatus` method in the wrapper class to check the status code and add the header when it is called:

```
public class MyHttpServletResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    public MyHttpServletResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
    }
    @Override
    public void setStatus(int sc) {
        if(sc == 200) {
            addIntHeader("x-success", 1);
        }
        super.setStatus(sc);
    }
}
```

Although this question was asked in relation to Struts 1, it applies to any web framework; my answer is based on work I did for JSF filters.

Comment: Interesting idea; I hadn't thought of doing it that way.  I already have the ResponseWrapper overridden in order to be able to check the status code after the servlet finishes (Servlet 2.4 spec), so it wouldn't be much extra effort to add the header at that point.  I'll give it a shot and let you know how it works (assuming that the Struts servlet explicitly sets the status code).

Comment: I just did a quick search against the Struts1 codebase, and don't see anywhere that it explicitly sets the status code.

Comment: As suspected, there is no default `setStatus()` call since the default status code of `CoyoteResponse` is already 200.  So no need for Struts to change the status unless it is something other than 200.

Comment: In that case try adding the header before calling `filter.doChain` and changing the value if the status code is set to something other than 200.

Comment: I bascially ended up doing something like that.  The only problem that is truly ugly is that the wrapper modifies a header that the filter set.  So the logic is split in 2 different places, which I don't like.

Comment: Putting the two classes in the same package can help logically group these items.  You could write a generic wrapper class that buffers the response without committing it, but that's a lot more work because there are several methods that you'll need to overload.